# retrieve from array for input parameter doesn't work

Tags: autohotkey

I want to do something like..

```
position := [100, 200]
Click, position[1], position[2]
```

but the above doesn't work, no error, but doesn't do click

```
Click, %position[1]%, %position[2]%
```

above gives error, variable name contains an invalid character

```
position := [100, 200]
p1 := position[1]
p2 := position[2]
Click, %p1%, %p2%
```

above works, but I don't want to assign dummy variables each time I need to click..

any help?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
click % position[1] . "," . position[2]
```

The % must be followed by a space or tab. It causes the command to use *expression mode*.

More information on "expression mode" can be found under **Help > Variables and Expressions > Variables > Retrieving the contents of variables**.

Comment: Thanks again! You must be the AHK master :D